# Insert image in table and do not move text inside of it

Tags: html, css

[The image I use (16x16)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9nO9.png)I am trying to insert the image into second TR>FirstTH but the text I had already in the th just dessapears. I already tryied float,position properties and adjusting the width and height of table, but still doesn't work. You can't change the HTML, it's the exercise requirement.

```css
table {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: Arial;
}

tr:nth-child(even)>td,
th {
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
}

th {
  background-color: rgba(88, 88, 88, 0.2);
}

tr:nth-child(n+2)>th {
  background-color: #E6F3FF;
}


/*This is the issue in the code*/

tr:nth-child(2) th:first-child {
  content: url("imagenes/euro.png");
  border: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table border="1" summary="Tipos de cambio">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Cambio</th>
      <th scope="col">Compra</th>
      <th scope="col">Venta</th>
      <th scope="col">M&aacute;ximo</th>
      <th scope="col">M&iacute;nimo</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Euro/Dolar</th>
      <td>1.2524</td>
      <td>1.2527</td>
      <td>1.2539</td>
      <td>1.2488</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Dolar/Yen</th>
      <td>119.01</td>
      <td>119.05</td>
      <td>119.82</td>
      <td>119.82</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Libra/Dolar</th>
      <td>1.8606</td>
      <td>1.8611</td>
      <td>1.8651</td>
      <td>1.8522</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Euro/Yen</th>
      <td>149.09</td>
      <td>149.13</td>
      <td>149.79</td>
      <td>148.96</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works adding :before in tr:nth-child(2) th:first-child

Comment: change "content" to background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use the  before to insert the image**

```
  <style>
        table {
            text-align: center;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid black;
            font-family: Arial;

        }


        tr:nth-child(even)>td,
        th {
            background-color: #FFFFCC;
        }

        th {
            background-color: rgba(88, 88, 88, 0.2);
        }

        tr:nth-child(n+2)>th {
            background-color: #E6F3FF;

        }

        /*This is the issue in the code*/

        tr:nth-child(2) th:first-child:before{
            content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9nO9.png");
            border: 0;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: left;
        }
    </style>
```